# genomic coordinate in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genomicranges, iranges

I am working on the [`TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene.html) data. I found that the length of the largest exon is 205012. How can I proceed to find the genomic coordinate of that exon?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you found the maximum range with the function `max`, you might want to consider using the function `which.max` to know which one is the max.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which.max()` on the Granges, something like below:

```
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
txdb = TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene
ex = exons(txdb)
ex$len = width(ex)
ex[which.max(ex$len)]

GRanges object with 1 range and 2 metadata columns:
      seqnames              ranges strand |   exon_id       len
         <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer> <integer>
  [1]    chr12 102591363-102796374      + |    164764    205012
  -------
  seqinfo: 93 sequences (1 circular) from hg19 genome
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question

Comment: Hi @Chris7, if it indeeds solves the problem, you can consider accepting it so that others know it works

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work